# What type of op-amp configuration is this?

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverter

[image]

If you need more info I will provide it. The op-amp board is piggybacked on an inverter driver board.

Comment: It's an integrator, but for what purpose is difficult to tell.

Comment: It's not any configuration until the relevant pins are connected to supply voltages or voltage references of some sort.

Comment: Depends what you connect to what pins. But with the capacitor is in the feedback loop, integration is part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a DC balance integrator for a full-bridge driver to null the DC offset, but it is prone to saturate unless it has large resistive feedback to limit the DC gain.  Also, the Vin+ should also have 100k in series to null Iin offset.

[image: schematic]
[image]
This is one of the worst readable "pretty" logic diagram that I have ever seen in 50 years. Simply put, it is illogical.

**The draftsperson needs to be trained on how to draw circuits that any engineer can read (skilled in the arts of electronics in any country).**

There are many other ways to use this as well if you know the allowable input  Vcm range and expected output.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, I didn't understand it very well :(

Comment: Tanks but in my case, the pin 3 (Noninverting input) is connected directly to GND

Comment: Then you might have an inverting amp

Comment: https://ibb.co/TcHN12v this is the full schematic

Comment: All necessary inputs ought to be in your question as well

Comment: I em sory for the bab diagram. Can you suggest som learning material for propery drawing diagrams.

Comment: @Nano go try to read Tektronix and HP schematics on web. Then you will learn, or use Sony , Hitachi TV methods. SChematics must follow traditional layout logic, not simply minimize traces with random layout, it must be left to right opposite to your reading text perhaps but also China follows this method and they read top down

Answer (score 3):

It is an integrator op-amp configuration with input on pin 2 and integrated output on pin 1.